# i want use while loop in my-sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

I have already using below code in SQL Server it is working fine, the same code I'm trying to use in mysql but i got error message

> 1064-you have an error in you sql systex; check the manual that corresponds to you mysql server version for the right systax to use Near'Declare @var Table (quantity int, width varchar(255) ) Insert @var Select at line 1

```
Declare @var Table 
    ( quantity int, width varchar(255) )
Insert @var
SELECT DISTINCT
    vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity, vtiger_inventoryproductrel.width
From
    vtiger_inventoryproductrel

Declare @var1 Table 
    ( quantity int, width varchar(255) )

Declare @Order_Item_Id varchar(10),@Qty int 
Set @Order_Item_Id = ''
While @Order_Item_Id < (Select Max(id) From @var)

Begin 
    Select @Order_Item_Id= Min(id) from @var where id > @Order_Item_Id
    Select @Qty = quantity From @var Where id = @Order_Item_Id
    While @Qty>0
    Begin 
        Set @Qty = @Qty-1 
        Insert into @var1 select * From @var Where id = @Order_Item_Id
    End 
End 

Select * From @var1
```

Comment: your syntax is totaly wrong... the error is from the beginning and doesnt have a relation to the while-loop. also you shoul write it in a procedure.

Comment: What did you find out when you checked the manual as suggested by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL is not Microsoft SQL Server.**

They have very different stored procedure languages.  In many ways, MySQL's stored procedure language is limited and less featureful compared to that of Microsoft.  Most users of MySQL don't write stored procedures at all, preferring to write business logic in the application layer in PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, C#, or other favorite language.

Here are a few points related to your example procedure:

- MySQL has no `Table` type.  You can't declare a variable as Table.
- Use [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html) to assign a value to a variable in a statement, not `INSERT`.
- Use [`SELECT...INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) to assign the result of a query to a variable.
- Each statement in a stored procedure needs a semicolon (`;`) terminator.
- You can't `SELECT ... FROM @var`.  Variables are not supported as table names.  You can do this by concatenating @var into a string, and then using that string as a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

That's not a complete list of what you would need to change to get this procedure to work in MySQL, it's just a sample of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary table in mysql

```
create temporary table var( quantity int, width varchar(255) );
create temporary table var1(quantity int, width varchar(255));
```

insert data to temporary table

```
insert into var(quantity, width )
SELECT DISTINCT vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity, vtiger_inventoryproductrel.width From vtiger_inventoryproductrel
```

To read data from mysql table not be used while, cursor used.
[Mysql Cursor Usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

also the temporary table in the var no contain column id